# rich:fileUpload submits whole form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Consider this snippet of code, which relies on JSF2 with RichFaces 4.5.0 as a used component library.

```
// some non-relevant attributes are omitted    
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{bean.uploadListener}">
      <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" render="imagePanel" immediate="true" />
</rich:fileUpload>
```

The given tag within a form submits the whole form. For instance, this is not the expected behaviour for me. I'd prefer that the component submits only the form properties of itself and skips the other form values within the same form, like ajaxSingle in RichFaces 3.

I did some research on this topic but did not find any conclusion how to manage the partial form submit for the fileUpload component, especially because there is no execute attribute for this tag, like in several other jsf ajax components.

I would appreciate any help on this case, especially how to manage that the fileUpload component only submits its own form values to the server.

Comment: You could put it in a separate form. Does it break something?

Comment: Unfortunately this would be only a dirty workaround for us, because the fileupload component is integrated in the UI which relies on a single form.

Comment: Anyone found a solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

Try `execute` attribute of `a4j:ajax`.

From docs:

> **execute**: Ids of components that will participate in the "execute" portion of the Request Processing Lifecycle. Can be a single id, a space or comma separated list of Id's, or an EL Expression evaluating to an array or Collection. Any of the keywords "@this", "@form", "@all", "@none", "@region" may be specified in the identifier list. Some components make use of additional keywords

I think that is exactly what you need.

More info: [Richfaces docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/vdldoc/a4j/ajax.html)

Comment: I am working on the same project an took over the issue. For testing purposes I removed the a4j:ajax completely and added an execute="@this" to the rich:fileUpload itself but still the whole form gets submitted. Strangely, though, as normal request parameters for the request URL and not as POST parameters for the partial ajax request.

Comment: have you tried adding `execute="@this"` on the `a4j:ajax`? or have you tried `f:ajax` instead of `a4j:ajax`?

Comment: I completely removed the `a4j:ajax`. `rich:fileUpload` itself does an ajax based upload (as expected) which already causes the full form submit as request parameters. This in fact leads to server errors in some cases due to incorrect escaping or too long request params. I used chrome's network monitor for debugging which clearly shows the mentioned behaviour. I switched to PrimeFaces' file upload for now which works just fine.

Comment: yes, I understood, I was asking if you had tried that another options also.. Sorry for my bad English :( . Thanks for your info, if I got any time I'll do some tests.

Comment: Your english is fine, don't worry :) I have not tried using `f:ajax` but it would surprise me if this changes the behavior of the initial upload process. Thanks for your suggestions and for looking into this!

Comment: @Roben Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, by discarding the RF upload completely and replacing it with the PrimeFaces one. The migration was relatively easy and the mechanics used for handling the uploads are nearly the same.